# Access hdfs file from spark worker node

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a spark application which needs to access and update an object stored as a file in hdfs. I'm unable to figure out how can I do it?

If I'm creating a FileSystem hdfs object and using it:

```
boolean fileExists = hdfs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(filePath));
if (fileExists){
    JavaRDD<MyObject> modelRDD = sc.objectFile(filePath);
}
```

I get:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 110.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 112)
```

java.lang.NullPointerException

This part of code runs at the worker so I'm assuming it fails because it doesn't have access to the Spark Context. In such a case, how can I access this hdfs file?

this hdfs file resides at the driver node. I can change replace hdfs with hive, storing data as byte array in hive, but even hive context access is not possible from worker node.

Adding full code for better understanding:

```
public class MyProgram {
    private static JavaSparkContext sc;
    private static HiveContext hiveContext;
    private static String ObjectPersistenceDir = "/metadata/objects";
    private static org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem hdfs;
    private static String NameNodeURI = "hdfs://<mymachineurl>:9000";

    // create and maintain a cache of objects for every run session
    //private static HashMap<String, MyObject> cacheObjects;

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("Inside constructor: creating Spark context and Hive context");
        System.out.println("Starting Spark context and SQL context");

        sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf());
        hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);

        //cacheObjects= new HashMap<>();

        //DataFrame loadedObjects= hiveContext.sql("select id, filepath from saved_objects where name = 'TEST'");
        //List<Row> rows = loadedObjects.collectAsList();
        //for(Row row : rows){
          //  String key =  (String) row.get(0) ;
          //  String value = (String) row.get(1);
          //  JavaRDD<MyObject> objectRDD = sc.objectFile(value);
          //  cacheObjects.put(key, objectRDD.first());
        //}


        DataFrame partitionedDF  = hiveContext.sql('select * from mydata');
        String partitionColumnName = "id";
        JavaRDD<Row> partitionedRecs = partitionedDF.repartition(partitionedDF.col(partitionColumnName)).javaRDD();


        FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Row>, MyObject> flatMapSetup = new FlatMapFunction<java.util.Iterator<Row>, MyObject>() {
            List<MyObject> lm_list = new ArrayList<>();
            MyObject object = null;

            @Override
            public List<MyObject> call(java.util.Iterator<Row> it) throws Exception {
                // for every row, create a record and update the object
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = it.next();

                    if (object == null) {
                        String objectKey = "" + id;
                        //object = cacheObjects.get(objectKey);
                        String modelPath = ModelPersistenceDir + "/" +'TEST'+ "/" + id;
                        JavaRDD<MyObject> objectRDD = sc.objectFile(objectPath);
                        object = objectRDD.collect().get(0);

                        // object not in cache means not already created
                        if(object == null){
                            if (object == null){
                                ObjectDef objectDef = new ObjectDef('TEST');
                                object = new MyObject(objectDef);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /*
                    / some update on object
                    */

                    String objectKey = "" + id ;
                    cacheObjects.put(objectKey, object);

                    // Algorithm step 2.6 : to save in hive, add to list
                    lm_list.add(object);
                } // while Has Next ends
                return lm_list;
            } // Call -- Iterator ends
        };//); //Map Partition Ends

        //todo_nidhi put all objects in collectedObject back to hive
        List<MyObject> collectedObject =  partitionedRecs.mapPartitions(flatMapSetup).collect();
}
```

Comment: If the data is stored on HDFS than driver and workers are able to access it. Also workers have access to sparkContext (please read spark documentation). I don't think you have a problem with data access. Also maybe instead of objectFile you wanted to use textFile

Comment: But when I'm trying to access the JavaSparkContext object from inside FlatMap function (which I assume will be running somewhere on worker node), it gives out NullPointerException.

Comment: Provide more information about the NPE

Comment: Updated the complete code in question, the NPE comes at **JavaRDD<MyObject> objectRDD = sc.objectFile(objectPath);** if try printing sc, it prints **null**

Comment: You cannot use JavaSparkContext inside a flatmap or foreach functions, will end up with null pointer exception. If you want to access extra data inside a flatamp then you need to collect to a list outside map and then use it inside flatmap.